# RSA or different information encryption method when work on Javascript side

Tags: javascript, encryption, glassfish, rsa, sha

I am building a service which is using a powerful client-side script to execute actions. All communications with a server are done via WebSockets. I am looking for a way to protect information which is transferring between server and client, so nobody with beginning/medium knowledge in Chrome debugging and HTTP scrapping can simply decode these data. The script itself will be deeply obfuscated.

I read there are some RSA libraries for javascript to encrypt/decrypt data, but I hear like RSA is old and slow and that's why I need someone's advice who is the guru in such things. I need for simple MIT library, no need for paid solutions and giant-sized packages.

Comment: "*The script itself will be deeply obfuscated.*" even then someone with *medium knowledge in Chrome debugging* will be able to decypher the data

Comment: @Luca please could you explain your thought

Comment: Security through obscurity doesn't exist

Comment: @Luca Does it mean there is no way to protect websockets channel from medium-level people?

Comment: @Epsiloncool `no way to protect websockets channel` whatever resides on the client side, consider accessible.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a way to protect information which is transferring between server and client,

That is SSL (https) for. There is no reason not to use SSL

> so nobody with beginning/medium knowledge in Chrome debugging and HTTP scrapping can simply decode these data. The script itself will be deeply obfuscated.

Often it is not so effective. If data are user entered or displayed,  there is no reason to encrypt them. If data are provided from the server and  not to be displayed, you can encrypt the data properly on the server side.

client-side encryption is usually feasible if you want to store or resend data encrypted or signed to other systems. 
Usually adding more complexity doesn't add security.

> I read there are some RSA libraries for javascript to encrypt/decrypt data

Just search for some https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441 or there is CryptoWebAPI https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API

the issue is - are you sure you need RSA? How would you manage and exchange keys? How would you ensure key authenticity?

> but I hear like RSA is old and slow

RSA is old and slow and yet used and secure (when implemented properly). RSA is used along other (symmetric) ciphers to ensure speed and effectiveness. It is called [hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)

There are two used asymetric systems, RSA and ECC. Regardless that using ssl will ensure confidentiality and integrity, in most of the cases you would need to really justify using RSA on the client side